# Does digest cycle runs while angularjs1 bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs

Does digest cycle runs while angularjs bootstrap?

As we know that angularjs has Bootstrap, compilation and data binding phase but I never come across with any doc/blog where it mention that digest cycle is a part of angularjs bootstrap.

Any thoughts/discussion will be really appreciated.

Comment: If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

Comment: I meant discussion among the contributors not with me. Regarding to angular guide, they havent mentioned anywhere that satisfy this question. I've done that already.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Life Cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle).

Comment: Thanks..Really helpful.